# Remove namespace from XSLT output

Tags: xml, web-services, xslt

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <s:Header xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" />
  <soapenv:Body>
    <swiftResponseResponse xmlns="http://webservice.sbi.com">
      <swiftResponseReturn>15617TS006140|DC768736|13321.49|04-05-2017 15:13:03|SWIFTINR|NA|FAIL-ACCOUNT UNAVAILABLE</swiftResponseReturn>
    </swiftResponseResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

`

my xslt code is `

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://webservice.sbi.com" exclude-result-prefixes="soapenv xsl  xsd xsi xs ">
  <!--<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>-->
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <!--<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>-->


  <xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="separator" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not(contains($text, $separator))">
            <swiftResponseReturnValue>
                <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
            </swiftResponseReturnValue>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <swiftResponseReturnValue>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before($text, $separator))"/>
            </swiftResponseReturnValue>
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $separator)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="separator" select="$separator"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
  <!--<xsl:template match="soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/xs:swiftResponseResponse/xs:swiftResponseReturn">-->
    <xsl:template match="soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/xs:swiftResponseResponse/xs:swiftResponseReturn">
    <!--<xsl:element name="Root">-->
      <!--<xsl:element name="swiftResponseReturn">
        <xsl:value-of select="xs:swiftResponseResponse/xs:swiftResponseReturn"/>
      </xsl:element>-->
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:variable name="tokenize">
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
                <xsl:with-param name="separator" select="'|'"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$tokenize"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <!--</xsl:element>-->

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

`

and my op is `

```
<swiftResponseReturn xmlns="http://webservice.sbi.com"
                     xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <swiftResponseReturnValue xmlns="">15617TS006140</swiftResponseReturnValue>
   <swiftResponseReturnValue xmlns="">DC768736</swiftResponseReturnValue>
   <swiftResponseReturnValue xmlns="">13321.49</swiftResponseReturnValue>
   <swiftResponseReturnValue xmlns="">04-05-2017 15:13:03</swiftResponseReturnValue>
   <swiftResponseReturnValue xmlns="">SWIFTINR</swiftResponseReturnValue>
   <swiftResponseReturnValue xmlns="">NA</swiftResponseReturnValue>
   <swiftResponseReturnValue xmlns="">FAIL-ACCOUNT UNAVAILABLE</swiftResponseReturnValue>
</swiftResponseReturn>
```

`

and expected output is 
`

```
<swiftResponseReturn>
   <swiftResponseReturnValue1>15617TS006140</swiftResponseReturnValue1>
   <swiftResponseReturnValue2>DC768736</swiftResponseReturnValue2>
   <swiftResponseReturnValue3>13321.49</swiftResponseReturnValue3>
   <swiftResponseReturnValue4>04-05-2017 15:13:03</swiftResponseReturnValue4>
   <swiftResponseReturnValue5>SWIFTINR</swiftResponseReturnValue5>
   <swiftResponseReturnValue6>NA</swiftResponseReturnValue6>
   <swiftResponseReturnValue7>FAIL-ACCOUNT UNAVAILABLE</swiftResponseReturnValue7>
</swiftResponseReturn>
```

`
i have used template to break code pipe separator format.but i don't want namespaces and also want unique identifier to distinguish each output.

Comment: hey can anyone help with updated output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `xsl:copy` to copy the `swiftResponseReturn` element, but that will include the namespace. You just need to create a new element name `xswiftResponseReturn` that is in no namespace.

Try replacing your current template with this..

```
<xsl:template match="xs:swiftResponseReturn">
  <swiftResponseReturn>
     <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
         <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
         <xsl:with-param name="separator" select="'|'"/>
     </xsl:call-template>
  </swiftResponseReturn>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that you don't really need the full path of the element in your template match here.

Comment: hey can i get output like  <swiftResponseReturnValue1>15617TS006140</swiftResponseReturnValue1>
   <swiftResponseReturnValue2 >DC768736</swiftResponseReturnValue2>

Comment: As this question was titled "Remove namespace from xlst", it might be less confusing if you asked a whole new question about numbering the elements if you can't work it out. (Hint: Add a third parameter to your `tokenize`, initially set to 1, but increment it with every call). I would recommend you add it as an attribute, rather than to the name though... `<swiftResponseReturnValue id="7">`

Comment: hey i  tried your suggestion but as i am beginner i wont be able to do it.

Comment: i have added new question here can you help

Comment: this is url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44969355/add-incremental-value-in-xslt-tag

Answer (score 2):

A more general solution: Change `<xsl:copy>` to `<xsl:element name="{name()}">`.

Of course, remember to change accordingly also the closing tag.

### Edit

Here you have the XSLT script for your changed requirements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xs="http://webservice.sbi.com" exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="separator" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not(contains($text, $separator))">
        <token>
          <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
        </token>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <token>
          <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before($text, $separator))"/>
        </token>
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
          <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $separator)"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="separator" select="$separator"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/xs:swiftResponseResponse/xs:swiftResponseReturn">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
      <xsl:variable name="tokens">
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
          <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
          <xsl:with-param name="separator" select="'|'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:for-each select="$tokens/token">
        <xsl:element name="swiftResponseReturnValue{position()}">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What has changed compared to your solution:

1. `tokenize` template returns a sequence of `token` elements
   and its result is saved in `tokens` variable.
2. Tokens from this variable are processed in a `for-each` loop.
3. Inside this loop there is created an alement. Its name is composed
   from `swiftResponseReturnValue` (constant text) and the position number of the current tag.
4. The content of this source tag is printed as the content of the
   just created tag.

And two additional changes at the beginning of the script:

1. The value of `exclude-result-prefixes` attribute was changed to
   `#all` (a simpler and more general solution).
2. I also added `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` to remove extra
   spaces and newline chars from the output.

Comment: hey can get output mention in comment